# Did your homepage, search engine or Chrome settings change?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

is your default search engine different than what you originally set it as?
  Did any of your other settings change without your consent?
There are several steps you can take to fix this issue which are given below.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reset your browser settings which will revert settings including your default search engine and homepage to the original state. (Note: passwords and bookmarks will not be reset.)

1.Click the Chrome menu Chrome menu on the browser toolbar
2. Select Settings.
3. Click Show advanced settings and find the "Reset browser settings” section.
4. Click Reset browser settings.

Check to see if there is a program on your computer or an extension that’s making unwanted changes. Find your extensions by going to Chrome Menu > Settings > Extensions and disable any extensions you don’t recognize.